# About isolated Power Supply Remote Control Mode

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, module, isolated

I am using mean well SCW12 series isolated dc dc smps power supply module. The thing that confuses me is the working principle of the r.c pin.
(PowerON: R.C. ~ -Vin > 4VDC or open ; Power OFF: R.C. ~ -Vin < 1VDC or short.)

That is, if the R.C pin is left in the floating position, will the power supply turn on?R.C. , - When 4 volts greater than Vin pin or left blank, power supply is active. Power is off if the ,R.C. is 1 volt or less relative to the -Vin pin, or shorted to the -Vin pin. Do I understand correctly?
[datasheet is here](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/SCW12/SCW12-spec.pdf)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *That is, if the R.C pin is left in the floating position, will the
> power supply turn on?*

The information: -

[image]

If the RC pin is open-circuit the device will power on. It won't power-on immediately from a cold-start but, as soon as the internal power rails are established, it will power on.

Comment: Hey Andy,thanks for feedback.if R.C.pin  has a voltage of 4 volts  or more related to -Vin will it turn on immediately?So are you saying that it will occur that latency  time because it is not directly connected to 4 volts or above?

Comment: If power has been established and RC taken low then taken high, it should produce an output very quickly. If a cold-start then it may take 10s or 100s of milliseconds @electronx

Comment: so if the r.c pin is in floating position, you call it "cold start" and you say that it will open with a delay on the basis of milliseconds, I understand. Thanks for your reply

Comment: A cold-start is when DC input power is newly applied @electronx